# Retrieving a Redux state, but also change another Redux state in same React Native component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a React component that currently just retrieves a state from Redux. Here is the general layout:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
     return { stuff: state.stuff };
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    // use 'stuff' from redux to build the Views
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

But now, what if I want to add a button that changes another Redux state called `other`?

To save the new Redux state, I know we have to create a dispatch to the action. ie,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
....
};
```

Then finally connect them:

```
connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

But my confusion is if I am already connecting with `mapStateToProps`, how can I also map it to `mapDispatchToProps` so that I can update the Redux state in the same component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, looks like I asked too early. I did a bit of reading and the parameters in `connect()` actually accepts both.

So like this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both ;-)

For example :

Action.js

```
export const textChanged = (newText) => {
    return { type: "TEXT_CHANGED", newText }
};
```

HomeScene.js :

```
import { textChanged } from "../actions;

...

render () {
    const { myText } = this.props;

    <TextInput 
     value={myText}
     onChangeText={(newText) => this.props.textChanged(newText)}
    />
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        myText: state.appContent.myText
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { textChanged })(HomeScene);
```

Reducer.js

```
case "TEXT_CHANGED":
        return {
            ...state,
            myText: action.newText
        };
```

Hope it helps !